# Keep map values into vector

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary

I have a set of objects that, during some initializations, I need to keep in an `std::map`, but after initialization I only need an `std::vector`. What efficient way is there to save the map's values into a vector?

I'm looking either for something with move semantics, or maybe there's some implementation of a map in Boost that would make this easier.

Comment: What is it that you're doing? Perhaps you can construct directly into the `vector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't this do the job:

```
your_vector.reserve(your_map.size());
for(auto& item : your_map) {
    your_vector.push_back(std::move(item.second));
}
```